# Sending a simple string to WCF service using POST

Tags: c#, android, json, wcf, http-post

I'm sending a string to WCF service using POST method in android. Like this,

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri);

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", msg));
httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

and on server side I'm doing this to get that string.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
UriTemplate = "{userId}/postlogs",
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
void PostLogs(string userId, RequestLogsData message);
```

I know I'm doing something very wrong, but I don't know what it is. Android not giving any error but this is not sending data to service.

Tell me any way to post this single string, by json or by xml.

This is my request class. Problem is in this I think.

```
[DataContract (Namespace="asd")]
public class RequestLogsData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

Checked my service through chrome extension `rest console` by sending this as a Raw body

```
<RequestLogsData xmlns="asd">
<message>
Messag Post
</message>
</RequestLogsData>
```

and setting content type to : `application/xml`

And this invoked the service as expected, now just guide me how can I invoke it through android app.

Comment: Have you tested your wcf service with "Fiddler"

Comment: I think I have wrongly implemented my service end point, so I didn't try that. And I have never used fiddler.

Comment: I have added my class too in which there would be an error.